# Probability of blind examination. Spanish and English

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Some time ago I had a statistical question.

Let's suppose that a student has to take a multiple-choice test.

There are a total of 20 questions, each question has 4 options. Each correct question adds one point. While each failure subtracts 0.25 points.

If to pass you have to get a 10 out of 20 questions, how many questions should be answered randomly so that it is more likely to get it right?

'
I ask this question here because I am aware that it is not valid to answer only 10 questions because in case you fail one, with a probability of 0.0563135147/1, you do not get the pass. So you have to answer more questions to have a higher probability of patching that failure and be able to reach at least 10 out of 20 correct answers.

Although obviously you can not answer 20/20 of the questions because the probability of failure is higher generating that the failure is more likely. Creating a parabola.

What interests me is what is the peak or the formula of the parabola. Being the peak where there is the highest probability of getting enough right to have a minimum of 10 points.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM0fn.png)

R = Answers made.

Y = Hits / 20≤Y≤10

X = Probability of correct answers / X=R×0.25

I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

It is optimal to answer all $20$ questions.

You want to get $10$ points, so you need to answer at least $12$ questions correctly. If you answer $n$ questions, then the number of correct answers follows a binomial distribution, $\text{Bin}(n,0.25)$. The probability of getting $12$ or more questions correct is $\sum_{k=12}^n\binom nk (0.25)^k(0.75)^{n-k}$. You can prove that this is an increasing function of $n$, so it is better to answer as many questions as possible.

If you randomly guess on all $20$ questions, the probability of getting $10$ points or more is about $0.1\%$. You would be better off studying!